# type '[[string:string]]'? has no subscript member

Tags: swift3, tableview

I'm trying to present into a table view information from another screen and I'm getting this error message:

> type '[[string:string]]'? has no subscript member

```
class TestListViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    let userTest = DataManager.getInstance().getRecord()
    let arrayOfDateString = DataManager.getInstance().getArrayOfKeys()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userTest!.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    //    cell.textLabel?.text = userTest[indexPath.row] - **here is the problem
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Your record"

        return cell


    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use an optional as data source array of a table view controller. That will solve your problem. And – unrelated – don't bridge cast an `UITableViewCell` to a `UITableViewCell`. Delete `as UITableViewCell`.

Comment: @vadian - can you pls give me, what do you mean?

Comment: Declare you data source array as non-optional (without question mark). And you have to call `reloadData()` on the table view somewhere after populating the data source array.

Comment: Can you please post some `userTest` sample data

Comment: this is the userTest : Optional([["2017-09-04 13:51:39": "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9BF9AA91-18FC-41F6-8F72-A9F5BF04D969/Documents/audioOfReport.m4a"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code -

```
cell.textLabel?.text = userTest[indexPath.row]
```

To this code -

```
cell.textLabel?.text = userTest![indexPath.row]
```

Comment: -I'm sorry still doesn't present well the table view